# SSAS OLAP yes/no Dimension including all rows on yes option

Tags: ssas, ssas-2016

I need to add a new dimension to my *OLAP* cube to filter some `rows`.

Essentially if the users select `"yes"` it should appear all rows.  If the users select `"no"` it should appear the rows identified.

I have a `column` in my factual table with `0` and `1` (`no`/`yes`)..

My problem is that I need to `"ignore"` this column if the users select yes and only look for it if the select no..

I thought on a Junk dimension but for this I need to have two attributes.

Any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "filtering some rows in cube" you mean apply filter if [No] member is selected in your dimension, correct? Otherwise show all measures like there is no filter.

Can you use SCOPE redirection to [All] member when [Yes] is selected?

```
SCOPE([YourDimension].[Yes]);
THIS=[YourDimension].[All];
END SCOPE;
```

This should work for every measure that you have in cube.

Moreover, even if cube ALTER is not allowed, you can achieve it in two steps way:

1. Create measure for ALL (unfiltered) value.
2. Show it only for certain members.

E.g. [CY 2013] = your [Yes]:

```
with
member [2013 is ALL] as ([Measures].[Order Count],[Date].[Calendar Year].[All])

member [2013] as
 iif([Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember is [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2013]
  or [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember is [Date].[Calendar Year].[All Periods]
  ,[2013 is ALL],[Measures].[Order Count])

select {[Measures].[Order Count],[2013 is ALL],[2013]} on 0
,[Date].[Calendar Year].members on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image: ALL_for_member]

But please try SCOPE as a first. Because it can be applied to any measure, even not created yet.

Comment: Alex Peshik thanks for your answer... However could you clarify a situation? I have to introduce this scope process into all my measures?

Comment: If you are using `SCOPE` - no need to mention measures for it. Because it's applied to all measures automatically. It will show [All] value for every corresponding measure in case of [Yes] selection.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create a dimension like this.  You need to handle this in the application where the users select yes/no.

Comment: I understand what you said..  I thought about and try to implement several ways but none work for me without implement to attributes.  My objective is to have only one because in a business analisys the use of to attributes to get this results do not make a sense..